# How to setup Ruby and RubyGems on CentOS?

Tags: centos, ruby, rubygems

I have a CentOS 5.5 (64-bit server)

I'd like to install Ruby 1.8.7 (current patch level) and RubyGems

What's the best way to go about this?

**disclaimer:** I'm a CentOS noob

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install it with default `yum install -y ruby ruby-devel rubygems`

Other way is to compile it by yourself

**Ruby**

```
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.7-p302.tar.gz
tar -zxvf ruby-1.8.7-p302.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.8.7-p302
./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/openssl
make
make install
```

**Rubygems**

```
wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
tar -zxvf rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
cd rubygems-1.3.7
ruby setup.rb config
ruby setup.rb setup
ruby setup.rb install
```

Check if installed

```
ruby -v
gem -v
```

Comment: NARKOZ, installing via packages is desired. My repository is only showing Ruby 1.8.5... :(

Comment: Actually, my repository doesn't even have a match for `rubygems`.

Comment: Then you should compile it yourself, follow instructions above. If you installed ruby 1.8.5, remove it with command `yum erase ruby`.

Comment: NARKOZ, I'm running into even more trouble. Patch level 302 of Ruby 1.8.7 does not have the `--with-openssl-dir` flag available for `configure`.

Comment: install it `yum install openssl openssl-devel`

Comment: that's not the issue. We have openssl, but `--with-openssl-dir` is not a valid flag for `configure`.

Comment: see what returns `which openssl`. try `./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin/openssl`. at least you can do just `./configure`

Comment: `--with-openssl-dir` is also not a valid configure option for this version of Ruby

Answer (score 1):

In what capacity are you trying to use Ruby? If you don't need it systemwide, Have you considered using RVM locally so you can install ruby into your local directory? Additionally you can install rvm systemwide. It takes some doing, but it's a better solution that tossing files across your server.

[Installing RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

I'd test it out first in your local directory until you get comfortable with it.